# Objective-c/IOS: What's the simplest way to play an audio file backwards

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, reverse

I've been struggling with this one for quite a while now, and there are no code examples of it being done on the net. Can anyone help me?

My app uses AVFoundation to record the audio.
@16 bit depth , 2 channels , WAV

I can access the bytes of the audio, I just don't know how to reverse it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In wave data samples are interleaved.  This means the data is organised like this.

```
Sample 1 Left | Sample 1 Right | Sample 2 Left | Sample 2 right ... Sample n Left | Sample n right
```

As each sample is 16-bits (2 bytes) the first 2 channel sample (ie for both left and right) is 4 bytes in size.

This way you know that the last sample in a block of wave data is as follows:

```
wavDataSize - 4
```

You can then load each sample at a time by copying it into a different buffer by starting at the end of the recording and reading backwards.  When you get to the start of the wave data you have reversed the wave data and playing will be reversed.

Edit: If you want easy ways to read wave files on iOS check out the [Audio File Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/Reference/reference.html).

Edit 2:

```
readPoint  = waveDataSize;
writePoint = 0;
while( readPoint > 0 )
{
    readPoint -= 4;
    Uint32 bytesToRead = 4;
    Uint32 sample;
    AudioFileReadBytes( inFile, false, maxData, &bytesToRead &sample );
    AudioFileWriteBytes( outFile, false, writePoint, &bytesToRead, &sample );

    writePoint += 4;
}
```

Comment: The difficulty is if it a wav file format that has a header and chunks.

Comment: @CocoaFu: Not really.  Apple provide you with a whole bunch of functions that deal with wave files.  The format isn't all that difficult to do one yourself.

Comment: @Goz Thanks, If it's not too much trouble to ask, could you provide a code sample to aid my understanding? How would this be achieved code-wise?

Comment: @DaveSmith122: There is a simple little code sample.  Its written off the top of my head so apologies for any mistakes but it should get you going and I'm sure you'll figure out how to open the files for reading and writing :)

Comment: Using @Goz answer I have created an small app which records user's voice and plays them in reverse. https://github.com/kiranb/iReversePlay hope this will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a single-chunk WAV file, try memmapping the file, and copying the samples out in reverse order, starting from the end of the file, into Audio Queue or RemoteIO buffers, during the callbacks, while using one of those APIs to play audio.  Stop copying before you get to the WAV/RIFF header (commonly the 1st 44 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

To reverse a audio, why not use the currentPlaybackRate in MPMediaPlayback (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)