# how to reverse order of NSMutableData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, reverse, nsmutabledata

I want to reverse bytes of `NSMutableData`.

I am generating nsmutabledata object from a audio file. and playing it using data. my purpose is play audio reverse.

If I can reverse the `NSMutableData` I will be success.

Here is my code

```
NSString *inputVideoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"chalne" ofType:@"mp3"];

NSMutableData *wave=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:inputVideoPath]];

avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:wave error:nil ];
[avPlayer prepareToPlay];
[avPlayer play];
```

Comment: It will not work. To play it in reverse it also needs to be an audio file (or segments) not just a reversed byte-array.

Comment: Then what is the way to play it in reverse order... Can you give me some code example please...

Comment: Check out this post, there is an example about how to do it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373977/objective-c-ios-whats-the-simplest-way-to-play-an-audio-file-backwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply reversing the order of the bits will not work, because a bytestream of sound data has a specific format. You'll want to reverse the samples, not the bytestream as a whole. However, as to answer 'how to reverse the bytes of an NSData', this ought to work (typed it out, may have typos):

```
NSData *myData;
const char *bytes = [myData bytes];
char *reverseBytes = malloc(sizeof(char) * [myData length]);
int index = [myData length] - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < [myData length]; i++)
    reverseBytes[index--] = bytes[i];
NSData *reversedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:reverseBytes length:[myData length]]
free(reverseBytes);
```

Comment: Very good anser it reverse the data but as you suggested it does not play.

May you please let me know the way how to play a audio file in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the above example and tested it.
now it can be used in a category:

```
- (NSData*) reversedData
{
    NSData *myData = self;

    const char *bytes = [myData bytes];

    NSUInteger datalength = [myData length];

    char *reverseBytes = malloc(sizeof(char) * datalength);
    NSUInteger index = datalength - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < datalength; i++)
        reverseBytes[index--] = bytes[i];

    NSData *reversedData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:reverseBytes length: datalength freeWhenDone:YES];

    return reversedData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSData *)reverseData
{
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    for(int i = (int)self.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
        [data appendBytes: &self.bytes[i] length:1];
    }
    return [data copy];
}
```